# Why grep fails within the script and not in the command line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a string which looks like this:

```
string=S1 s5 S0 s3 s2 S11 s13
```

elements with capital S have to be extracted to another string, so I want this:

```
string1=s5 s3 s2 s13
string2=S1 S0 S11
```

Order of the elements in substrings doesn't matter.

I wrote a solution like this:

```
string1=$(echo $string | grep -o 's[^ ]\+')
string2=$(echo $string | grep -o 'S[^ ]\+')
```

and it worked (I also did it with grep -o 's[0-9]\+' and instead of echo did <<< after grep, everything worked).

Unfortunately it may sometimes happen that my string only has capital S like this:

```
unfortunatestring=S0 S1 S5 S11 S2
```

the script simply stops at the line 
   string1=$(echo $string | grep -o 's[^ ]+')

but if I run my script in debug mode with sh -x everything works fine.

I assume doing command substitution on grep which fails to return a value causes the script to stop, my question is why? I don't mind if the string1 is empty, but I mind if my script stops.

Can you please give me the solution which will always create string1 and string2 out of string and it isn't a problem if string1 and string2 are empty.

I'm new to bash, and I assume this can also be done with sed or awk.

Comment: This really feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you tells us what you are trying to DO with the strings we can probably help you better.

Comment: I have input string which has capital S and non-capital s elements, and it's always followed by number, so it looks like S1, s15, S3, s0, s1, s2 etc, I want to separate capital S elements to another string, it can't be explained simpler.

Comment: Later I will use string with minor s in  for loop to write them kill s15, kill s0, kill s2 etc (in separate rows) - I already did this!

Comment: with capital S string I will do something more complex, but my script fails only in case I described.

Comment: I cannot replicate the hang.  Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that causes the script to hang in your setup?

Comment: when my initial string has only captial S elements, or only non-capital s elements code stops exactly at the grep line, I did echo before those lines, and after them, so the problem is when grep doesn't have anything to return.

Comment: `I did echo before those lines, and after them` . I am not sure if this could find the exact place the script stopped. You might use the `set -ex` option in the beginning of the script to find exactly where the script stops. It dumps the command being executed to the stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
string="S1 s5 S0 s3 s2 S11 s13"
string1=$(sed 'S/[ ]*s[0-9]*[ ]*//g' <<<"$string") #removing big s
echo "$string1"
string2=$(sed 's/[ ]*S[0-9]*[ ]*//g' <<<"$string") #removing small s
echo "$string2"
```

Comment: Any idea why grep failed?

Comment: @AleksandarDemić I have updated my sed script. No idea why grep failed. It worked for me